# Multiple absolute positioned elements overlapping

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am making a website with a slide type layout. Currently, I am working on the following two slides:
[image: Slide 1]
and
[image: Slide 2]

I want to have a button on each slide (like in slide 1).

I have applied the following rules to the button:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 5%;
```

I have two buttons : "Know me" and "My skills".

Currently, both buttons are overlapping (that's why you can't see the "Know me" button).

What rules can I apply so that both buttons appear at the same position in their respective slides?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: @Paulie_D thanx for the comment but I thought that this question doesn't require the full code because the problem was only related to the positioning of the buttons. Anyway, I got an answer that solved my issue. Thanx again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements with `position: absolute` are located relative their closest parent element with `position: relative`. To have your buttons appear in their relevant slide frames be sure to assign `position: relative` to each frame.

```css
.slide {
  height: 80px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 4px;
}

#slide-1 {
  background-color: red;
}

#slide-2 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="slide-1" class="slide">
  <button type="button">Button 1</ button>
</div>

<div id="slide-2" class="slide">
  <button type="button">Button 2</ button>
</div>
```

Comment: i'd set it up exactly like this, couldn't figure out why it wasn't working, inspected element and realised i hadn't closed a /div so slide-2 was nested inside slide-1 :D